Using SQL, is there a way to transform a dataset that makes new columns for data points within the table?
I've been attempting to clean a dataset for a project, but ran into issues when trying to transform the data. The provided problem set contains a similar scenario to the real dataset. If you look closely at the [Original] dataset, the number of fruit and the color will both separately add up to the "total count" row, which is 10. My goal is to break those descriptive variables out of the data and align them each with their own columns, as seen in the [Desired Outcome]. This would allow me to visualization the data in Tableau with no issues.
Upon researching my problem, my initial thought with that the solution had to be associated with a pivot or unpivot function. However, because there seems to be two different descriptive variables within the data, I didn't find much success. It's worth noting that the original dataset is populated with hundreds of thousands of rows, so a simple creation and translation of a new table may not be easily executed.
Overall, I am completely unsure how to approach this problem. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Original:

Desired Outcome:


The maximum number of query columns in PostgreSQL is around 1600. How many columns do you want to have?

Hi - please don't use images, especially of data. Instead use editable text, formatted as tables, so that if someone wants to try out a solution they can just copy your data. Also, given that when cleaning up data it is common to normalise it (which then can make the data much easier to subsequently manipulate), I wondering why you are going in the opposite direction and attempting to fully denormalise it? What are you planning to do with the data once you've got it into the desired format?

Growing the number of columns as the number of distinct Chraracteristics grows is generally not a good idea. Would Food and one composite JSON field like {"total count":10, "apple":3, ... "red":5, "yellow":4, ...} be suitable for your case? And what about 'Orange' the color and 'Orange' the fruit?

I stared doing this in oracle sql before I saw that you are using postgresql but maybe this can help you anyway? I assume postgresql do not allow 2 columns with the same name either...(orange)
Edit. postgresql solution
https://dbfiddle.uk/CNr1zblm
 with data as (
        Select 'Fruit' as Food,10 as Value, 'Total count' as Characteristics, null as Color, null as Location, null as "date" from dual union all
          Select 'Fruit' ,3 , 'apple' , null , null , null  from dual union all
          Select 'Fruit' ,1 , 'orange' , null , null , null  from dual union all
          Select 'Fruit' ,4 , 'banana' , null , null , null  from dual union all
          Select 'Fruit' ,2 , 'cherry' , null , null , null  from dual union all
          Select 'Fruit' ,2 , null , 'red' , null , null  from dual union all
          Select 'Fruit' ,2 , null , 'yellow' , null , null  from dual union all
          Select 'Fruit' ,2 , 'cherry' , 'orange' , null , null  from dual 
        )
        select 
          Food,
          max(case when Characteristics = 'Total count' then Value end) as "Total count",
          max(case when Characteristics = 'apple' then Value end) as apple,
          max(case when Characteristics = 'orange' then Value end) as orange,
          max(case when Characteristics = 'banana' then Value end) as banana,
          max(case when Characteristics = 'cherry' then Value end) as cherry,
          max(case when Color = 'red' then Value end) as red,
          max(case when Color = 'yellow' then Value end) as yellow,
          max(case when Color = 'orange' then Value end) as orange_color
        from data
        group by Food;


Unlike Oracle there is no need for from dual in PostgreSQL
